# How do I get all data when I join 2 uneven tables with a sum function involved?

Tags: sql, join, sum, missing-data

Here is a very simplified example of the problem I am having.  TableA and TableB above represent queries from a larger table.

[TableA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RuZOB.jpg)

```
 JOB | DELIVERED
0001 |      1000
0002 |       500
0003 |      1000
```

[TableB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjTdA.jpg)

```
 JOB | DEFECT | QTY
0001 |      A |   2
0001 |      B |   1
0001 |      C |   3
0002 |      A |   1
0002 |      B |   5
0002 |      C |   2
```

If I write the statement

```
SELECT 
    TableA.JOB, 
    TableA.DELIVERED, 
    sum(TableB.QTY) AS REJECTS 
from 
    TableA LEFT JOIN TableB ON 
        (TableA.JOB = TableB.JOB) 
GROUP BY 
    TableA.JOB, 
    TableA.DELIVERED
```

[I get the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLRUL.jpg)

```
 JOB | DELIVERED | REJECTS
0001 |      1000 |       6
0002 |       500 |       8
```

[What I actually want is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6dm9.jpg)

```
 JOB | DELIVERED | REJECTS
0001 |      1000 |       6
0002 |       500 |       8
0003 |      1000 |       0
```

How do I get it to give me what I want?  I found a solution, but it seems unreasonable to me and in practice takes too long.

```
SELECT 
    TableD.JOB, 
    TableD.DELIVERED, 
    TableC.REJECTS 
FROM 
    TableA TableD LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT 
            TableA.JOB, 
            sum(TableB.QTY) AS REJECTS 
        from 
            TableA TableA INNER JOIN TableB TableB ON 
                (TableA.JOB = TableB.JOB) 
        GROUP BY TableA.JOB) TableC
```

[This statement gives](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaYYG.jpg)

```
 JOB | DELIVERED | REJECTS
0001 |      1000 |       6
0002 |       500 |       8
0003 |      1000 |
```

Comment: Your 1st query does NOT return what you say...

Comment: Simply adjust to `coalesce(sum(TableB.QTY),0) AS REJECTS`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are working on SQL Server 2008, try `isnull` function like below:

```
SELECT TableD.JOB, TableD.DELIVERED, isnull(TableC.REJECTS,0)
FROM TableA, TableD 
LEFT JOIN (select TableA.JOB, sum(TableB.QTY) AS REJECTS from TableA
           inner join TableB on (TableA.JOB = TableB.JOB) 
           group by TableA.JOB) TableC
```